# How to create one page app on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, windows-phone-8.1

I am doing app for Windows Phone 8.1 and I am want to know your opinion about how to solve followed problem. The app is designed to be one-page, but I dont know how to solve it, because no of default windows controls fit to my requirements. Design is here:
[image: Design]

So, it is somethink like double pivot. In second menu will be pictures or text or somethink, which will navigate between content by topic. Each Content could be splited into separate views, which will be changing by touch movement. Points color (or design or whatever) will be changing (somethink like this [slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html).

So, what do you think about it, it is possible? And if yes, so how? I will probably need create custrom controls and panel. Do you have any tips, which will push me the right way? How would you solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Dude, that's one really broad question for a Q&A format style site like SO. I'd point you towards the parts of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that cover this sort of thing. Cheers!

Comment: I dont need to solve it here, I just want know what do you think about it and how you should do it, because i havent got expericence with something like this.

Comment: I would suggest you to have one page with different usercontrols. You can create usercontrols as per your UI requirement and add those to page.